# Vertical line in a table with merged cells

Tags: tables, cell

Here 's my problem: I would like to reproduce the following image in Latex in order to automate the generation of my documents:
[image: Table sample]

(It's french with meaningless data haha)

For now I managed to get the layout, however I didn't manage to get the vertical line thick enough like in the previous picture. The verticale line should have the height of just 1 line even if there are multiple lines in the cell.

Here's the code:

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l c X}
        Description & \textcolor{blue}{$|$} & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi at mi non nunc interdum molestie. \\
        & & multilignes\\
        Validation & $|$ & Ceci est un texte \\
        & & multilignes\\
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

How should I do it ?

Thank you !

Comment: Helloc, you can try replacing your `$|$` with `\bluevrule` defined as `\newcommand{\bluevrule}[0]{\color{blue}{\rule[-0.5ex]{1mm}{3ex}}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I propose this variant, with a slightly simpler code, and a completely different solution, vased on a customised `description` environment:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[svgnames, x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newenvironment{mydescription}[1][descr]{%
\renewcommand*{\descriptionlabel}[1]{\eqmakebox[{#1}][l]{##1}\hskip1.25em\textcolor{NavyBlue!60}{\rule[-0.8ex]{1pt}{2.5ex}}}%
\description[labelsep=1.25em, leftmargin= \dimexpr\eqboxwidth{#1}+1em+\labelsep + \fontdimen 2\font]}%
{\enddescription}

\begin{document}

 \noindent \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l@{\hskip1.25em\textcolor{NavyBlue!60}{\rule[-0.8ex]{1pt}{2.5ex}}\hskip1.25em}X}
        Description & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi at mi non nunc interdum molestie. \newline multilignes\\
        Validation & Ceci est un texte \newline multilignes\\
    \end{tabularx}
\bigskip

    \begin{mydescription}
        \item[Description] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi at mi non nunc interdum molestie. \newline multilignes\\
       \item[Validation] Ceci est un texte \newline multilignes\\
    \end{mydescription}

    \begin{mydescription}[descra]
        \item[Long description] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi at mi non nunc interdum molestie. \newline multilignes\\
       \item[Validation] Ceci est un texte \newline multilignes\\
    \end{mydescription}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution based on the `multirow`package:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\customrulesep}{\vrule width 2pt}
\newcommand{\rulesepOverOneRow}{\multirow{1}{*}{\customrulesep}}
\newcommand{\coloredRulesepOverOneRow}{\multirow{1}{*}{\color{blue}\customrulesep}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l c X}
        Description & \coloredRulesepOverOneRow & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi at mi non nunc interdum molestie. \\
        & & multilignes\\
        Validation & \rulesepOverOneRow & Ceci est un texte \\
        & & multilignes\\
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

You can adapt the thickness by changing `width 2pt` to any dimension you like.

Result

[image]

Enjoy!