# With tabularray package, add vertical lines between a few specific table cells, with command in cell itself

Tags: tables, cell

I’m using the `tabularray` package, and **I’d like to insert vertical border segments between just a few specific cells in a table**, as shown in the left-hand table below.  As seen in the MWE code, I can get such lines by using the `hline` option together with the row numbers of the cells in question.  However, **I’d like to do this without using the absolute row numbers** if possible — ideally, with a command in one of the cells neighbouring the border itself, something like the “desired source” code in the MWE — so that I can add/remove rows elsewhere in the table and have these border segments stay with the correct line of content.

(In my eventual use-case there are also multi-row and multi-column cells, and cells with background colours, so a solution that plays well with these would be strongly preferred.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\newcommand{\cellvline}{\textbullet} % placeholder to be redefined

\begin{document}
Desired output:
\begin{tblr}{vline{1,Z},hline{1,Z},vline{2}={3}{solid},vline{4}={2}{solid}}
  a1 & a2 & a3 & a4 \\
  b1 & b2 & b3 & b4 \\
  c1 & c2 & c3 & c4 \\
\end{tblr}
\hspace{2em}

Desired source:
\begin{tblr}{vline{1,Z},hline{1,Z}}
  a1 & a2 & a3 & a4 \\
  b1 & b2 & b3 & \cellvline b4 \\
  c1 & \cellvline c2 & c3 & c4 \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510921/vertical-line-in-a-table-with-merged-cells?rq=1

Comment: @jsbibra: Indeed, that answer is just the sort of thing I was looking for — except not in `tabularray`, and I can’t see how to adapt it, since (as far as I can find) the `tabulararray` equivalents of `\multirow`/`\multiline` don’t allow separators to be included with the column specification.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and as is seems the only way:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,Z}={solid},  vline{1,Z}={1-Z}{solid},
             vline{2}={Z}{solid, fg=red}, 
             vline{Y}={Y}{solid,fg=blue},
             colspec= {Q[c]}
             }
  a1 & a2 & a3 & a4 \\
  b1 & b2 & b3 & b4 \\
  c1 & c2 & c3 & c4 \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
You can inset `\SetVline in table cell, however, you still need to tel in which row is cell ...

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,Z}={solid},  vline{1,Z}={1-Z}{solid},
             colspec= {Q[c]}
             }
  a1 & a2 & a3 & a4 \\
  b1 & b2 & b3 & \SetVline{2}{blue5} b4 \\
  c1 & \SetVline{3}{red5}  c2 
          & c3 & c4 \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Result is the same as before.

Comment: Unfortunately (sorry if this wasn’t clear in the question) using the row position counted from the bottom is no better than counted from the top — either way, the line segments are not tied to the particular row contents, so may get misplaced from them if more rows are added below/above.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine, you can insert row and column number absolutely, if you wish. But, more important, unfortunately  there is no other way as to explicate tell in which row is particular cell. See edited answer.